# DAO Tokens don't appear in Mist

Tags: ether, the-dao

I had approximately 7600 DAO tokens sitting in my Mist wallet. After the hard fork, I sent these tokens to another Ether account in another wallet that I keep on a currency exchange site.

Here is the Etherscan 
transaction record:
[0xe7f042a442f8eddd13d2b2aba6b871eea31f28c53eea5df49ad6ff89e35702da](http://etherscan.io/tx/0xe7f042a442f8eddd13d2b2aba6b871eea31f28c53eea5df49ad6ff89e35702da)

The transaction appears as unconfirmed in Mist, and the DAO tokens or their ETC equivalent are not displayed in the receiving wallet.

How can I reclaim my Ether?

Comment: Do you have a link to the record of the transaction? How do you know the transaction never completed?

Comment: What do you mean by never completed? Are all the token still on the first address? If so just use this address to withdraw tokens to ETH.

Comment: Yes, I have an etherscan record. The transaction did not complete because 1) it is still unconfirmed in my Mist ether wallet and 2) DAO tokens or their ETC equivalent , have not been received into the other Ether wallet i sent them to. I (naively) thought they would be converted back into ether.

Comment: In order to use the Withdrawal contract, don't the tokens have to be in the Etherwallet? Now they are neither in the originating wallet nor in the one I sent them to. They are shown as an incomplete (unconfirmed) transaction in the wallet.

Comment: Can i send you copy of the Etherscan transaction?

Comment: http://etherscan.io/tx/0xe7f042a442f8eddd13d2b2aba6b871eea31f28c53eea5df49ad6ff89e35702da

Comment: Could you rewrite the question from scratch and explain step by step what your issue is and highlight where tokens are supposed to be and what finally your issue is? The question in the current form reads like it's written bottom-up. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, 5chdn. Here is my question from scratch.  I had approx 7600 DAO tokens sitting in my Ether wallet (Mist). After the hard fork, I sent these tokens to another Ether account in another wallet that I keep on a currency exchange site. The tokens "left " my Ether wallet but the transaction was not confirmed. They did not arrive in the other Ether wallet either. So where are they? Can I retrieve them or are they lost? Here is etherscan transaction record. 0xe7f042a442f8eddd13d2b2aba6b871eea31f28c53eea5df49ad6ff89e35702da

Many thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Also, please use [meta to discuss closed question disputes](http://meta.ethereum.stackexchange.com/) and use the [edit button](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/posts/8351/edit) to add additional information to the question instead of adding comments. Thanks!